# iOS, fopen hangs / gets stuck

Tags: ios, fopen

My method to open and read from a file is getting stuck at fopen().

Everyone says it's something about FIFO and having to open the other end (it's a bloody file, what first in first out?), but no one even gives a hint as to what to do.

```
const int arraySize = 256;
char tempArray[arraySize];

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(
                                                     NSDocumentDirectory, 
                                                     NSUserDomainMask, YES
                                                     ); 
NSString* docDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString* file = [docDir stringByAppendingString:@"/example_01.txt"];

NSLog(file);

//converting to C string
[file getCString:tempArray maxLength:arraySize encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

printf("see %s\n", tempArray);

FILE *lalala;

printf("file pointer befoer: %p", lalala);
lalala = fopen(tempArray, "rb+");

printf("file pointer: %p", lalala);

fseek(lalala, 4, SEEK_SET);

char readin[5];
readin[4] = '\n';
fread(readin, 1, 4, lalala);

fclose(lalala);
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your tempArray is too small and memory gets overwritten.

Try `char* tempArray = [file UTF8String];` instead.

Comment: Set it to a 1000. No go. I can actually create/over-ride a file with "w".

Comment: What about leaving out the "b" and just make the open mode "r+"?

Answer (score 1):

Are you considering in using NSFileHandle instead?

Since I am not trying you code, but as you know fopen is a low-level c function, I am not sure if there are some limits on iOS (All of Apps on iOS are running in "sandbox" and have no permissions to read & write anything beside it. )

Comment: I see. How about try this code: FILE *f = fopen([file cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding], "r"); with only "read" option.

Comment: No go. :/ I'm seriously considering using NSFileHandle and re-writing the C code given to me (heavens help me). But I'm having trouble with NSFileHandle too with "Bad File descriptor"s. /sigh

Comment: I am thinking that are you making the path of your file correctly? Since you are logging the path, have you tried to open it with Finder (If you are running in iOS Simulator) and see if it's correct?

Comment: Well, I can create empty files with the path, it's just that it get stuck there too. It also works with CFURLCreateFromFileSystemRepresentation(), returning a valid CFURL in which I use as a parameter for AudioFileOpenURL().

Comment: OK, Got NSFileHandle sorted out. Was stupid and called the wrong method. For some reason, you can read the file if you open it for writing ...

Comment: @xuzhu OK finally resolved it and am now feeling like an idiot. `readin[4] = '\n';` was the problem, I terminated my string wrong, and it gummed up all the printf()s. /facepalm

Answer (score 1):

the cause of the problem :

```
readin[4] = '\n';
```

I terminated my string wrong.

In Xcode, it gummed up the printf() that followed to display `readin`, and appears to have messed up `printf("file pointer: %p", lalala);` that came before it as well.

Feeling like a nitwit now.

Many thanks to Xuzhe and Hollance for trying to help me out.